# Net 6 Cors give error even after enabling it

Tags: angular, cors, .net-6.0

In my web project with .net6 and angular cors is giving error even after enabling it in my project file my port is 4420 on frontend and 7126 on backend

my **project.cs**

```
var policyName = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: policyName,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder
                            .WithOrigins("https://localhost:4420","http://localhost:4420") // specifying the allowed origin
                            .AllowAnyMethod() // defining the allowed HTTP method
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowCredentials(); // allowing any header to be sent
                      });
});

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser,ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(policyName);
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseIdentityServer();


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();
```

the request in my component in angular is following

```
 this.http.get("https://localhost:7126/images/logo.png", { withCredentials: true , responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe((response) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.imageUrl = reader.result as string;
    };
    console.log("test");
    reader.readAsDataURL(response);
  });
```

These are images of the errors in console log and network request
[console log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsUlQ.png)
[network request details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPORc.png)

Comment: seems like an issue with preflight OPTIONS verb.  Check IIS for allowing that verb.

Comment: @pcalkins i am sorry is there any tut or hint how to do that, also i am not running on iis

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis#http-verbs  To check if you've set IIS to not allow OPTIONS...   you might also want to install the CORS module: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

Answer (score 0):

[The CORS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#enable-cors) warn in a big yellow box that :

> [UseCors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.corsmiddlewareextensions.usecors) must be called in the correct order. For more information, see [Middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order). For example, UseCors must be called before UseResponseCaching when using UseResponseCaching.

The order of middleware `Use` calls matters. Middleware declared earlier in the pipeline is called first. The [Middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order) page shows that CORS should be enabled after Routing but before Authentication and Authorization.

The order should change to :

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(policyName);
app.UseAuthentication();
...
```

Comment: Corrected the order still the same

Comment: should be before "app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();" too, no?